# my route /favicon.ico not working in my flask instance

Tags: python, flask, favicon

Here is my flask code:

```
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
# my icons are in static/icons, so the favicon file is: static/icons/favicon.ico
return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static', 'icons'),
                           'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
```

if I go to http://:8080/favicon.ico, I see the icon when running flask, but when I go to one of the other flask-served pages, I see the generic icon.  I thought that the route /favicon.ico should work for all pages served by the flask instance.

Comment: Your browsers debugger should tell you what happens or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do that `route` the icon will apply only on `127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico` but other pages will not be affected

**the solution**
you can add...

```
<link rel="icon" href="static/icons/favicon.ico" sizes="32x32">
```

for each html page
or simply add it to base file if you are using jinja2

Comment: that works great.  Thank you.  I thought I had read that you don't need that in the html files, but *obviously* I was wrong.